# Declarative pipeline - Running a shell command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a jenkins pipeline script that I am updating wish to use the following shell command:

```
sh script: """
  export PATH=\"${PATH}\":\"${WORKSPACE}\"
  BASE_DIR=$(dirname $0)
  source "${BASE_DIR}/shellscript.sh"
                               
  helm uninstall ${helmReleaseName}  --namespace ${kubenamespace} 
"""
```

And the result always is:

```
Errors encountered validating Jenkinsfile:
```

I've played around with it.
But it fails the validation? The question is why?

Thanks

Comment: More information is needed regarding the exact error, but looks like you need to escape the **$** signs that are not used for string Interpolation. `BASE_DIR=\$(dirname \$0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative pipeline with 'sh' step will look like:

```
stage ("Preparing") {
    steps {
        sh'''
          export PATH=\"${PATH}\":\"${WORKSPACE}\"
          BASE_DIR=$(dirname $0)
          source "${BASE_DIR}/shellscript.sh"
                               
          helm uninstall ${helmReleaseName}  --namespace ${kubenamespace}
        '''
    }
}
```

Take a look [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/)

Comment: If you use single quotes **'''** instead of double quotes **"""** the String Interpolation will not work and the parameters will not be evaluated, so multi line double quotes should be used.

Comment: It worked for me by changing double quotes to single quotes and the parameters were evaluated.